# use text and use as command?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

i whant to build a script to extract the word from a file in a command:

for example:
in my file i keep my username , how can i export the username without knowing the username as part of my command , which my command is : suspend here should be the word exported?

From my file which has the text inside "JOHN" how can i tell the command : suspend that the username is JOHN ?

how can i cat/grep/sed the text from the file as part of command :

something like suspend |cat file , i have try that but the suspend command does not take the username , so there should be something different .

my ideea where like this

```
#!/bin/sh
username=cat my-file;

suspend $username ,
```

but i had no succes , because my $username is not display from the cat , the cat is shows it but thats all that is doing.

Comment: What does your text file look like?

Comment: Q: I want to build a script to extract the word from a file in a command (for example, "JOHN").  A: OK - you can do this.  But first, you need to tell us how this file is structured?  How is the program going to locate "JOHN"?  By character offset (character 20)?  By word position (2nd word)?  You need to tell us more about the file :)

Comment: The file is simple its content is only the username which some other programs generate it , today can be john , tomorow can be joe , in the file is only one position with the username in it , john or joe , that text i whant to cat it somehow and use it as part of my command i was thinkin like this  username=cat file; suspend $username , something like that but my ideea isnt working.

Comment: Linux suspend command is used to suspend shell execution, what is it that you are trying to do with a name from a text file? If by `suspend` you mean to lock their account then `usermod -L user` is the command for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following syntax

```
  username=$(cat my-file)
```

you might also use backquotes like

```
  username=`cat my-file`
```

but the `$(`...`)` notation is preferable: it can be nested and is more readable.

Please read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (it will teach you a lot, even if it can be criticized)

Your usage of `suspend` is incorrect, and I don't understand what you want to do with it. What would suspending a user mean to you? Perhaps you want to use [pgrep](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pgrep.htm) or `pkill` (to kill all the processes of that user, which I feel is too harsh)...?

Comment: this   username=`cat my-file` works just perfect , thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The command to read a line is, shockingly, named "read":

```
$ cat file
John
$ IFS= read -r username < file
$ echo "$username"
John
```

"cat" is the command to concatenate files.

Setting `IFS=` and using the `-r` arg to read are so that read handles leading white space and/or backslashes as-is rather then interpreting them. If you KNOW your file can never contain those or you want read to strip leading white space and/or interpret backslashes than you can get rid of those.