# Why "cat a.txt | xargs vi" destroy the bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

The content of `a.txt` : `ba.txt`

When I type `cat a.txt | xargs vi`, vi open the `ba.txt` and everything seems to be OK...

But when I exit the vi, I find my bash is abnormal..I can't see the instructions I type in. I typed `ls`. I can't see it, but when I press the enter, the result is displayed(in a strange way..)...(After typed `ls`,I typed `ll`. There are some Chinese characters,please ignore it ).. And the bash is like this:

[image: bash]

Could anybody explain this?

Comment: @doubleDown I'm trying to learn how to use `xargs` and pipes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bash` shell is not destroyed. It is just that your terminal is in some bad state -because you sent strange bytes to it- (a terminal has some state -and the terminal emulator and the kernel manage that state, which persists after the process having wrongly changed it. See e.g. the [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) command, the [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) man page about `/dev/tty`, and the [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function). Type (perhaps blindly) the `reset` command (or `stty sane`) to reset the terminal.

Most terminals respond to [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (for ugly details, read about [termcap(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/termcap.5.html) which is related to configuring these escape codes). A command sending arbitrary -or random- bytes may happen to send some escape sequences which might damage the behavior of your terminal.

However, your use of `vi` is probably wrong. For programmable edition, consider using [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) or [ed(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_ed.htm); or perhaps `emacs --batch` ....

If you just want to edit the file `ba.txt` named by the line inside `a.txt` you could just run:

```
 vi $(cat a.txt)
```

or better yet, using the standard `EDITOR` variable (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html))

```
 $EDITOR $(cat a.txt)
```

Read also the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/). You might use backquotes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17715005/841108), but I don't recommend using them.

---

For historical reasons, terminals emulate [tty](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)-s (follow that link, it explains a lot), which were incredibly complex and arcane physical devices. You are probably too young to have seen them (outside of a museum). I worked on some, as a teenager, in the 1970s. It was incredibly fun and noisy - a sort of electromechanical communicating typewriter.

<sup>Jesus, I'm getting old, no one know today what a typewriter really is....</sup>

Comment: Why what? The terminal has been screwed up (and it has some internal state, managed by the kernel and the terminal emulator or physical device, independently of the shell or program using it). You need to reset the terminal to some reasonable state!

Comment: I mean why terminal will been screwed up.. Sorry for misunderstanding..(According to your edits...the reason is every complex?)

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. It just explains how to revert back to the normal state, not why it happens in the first place. See the other answer for an explanation.

Comment: I improved my answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on “strange bytes”? What is it that causes the terminal to be garbled and why is it required that vim needs to connect to the terminal and not the pipe to avoid that?

Comment: `script -a debug.log`
`echo "abc" |xargs vi`

and click Ctrl+d to end the script session
You will see the ansi sequence logged in debug.log
the ANSI sequence will mess you screen

Comment: I don't know what is the meanning of $...Counld you please elaborate it?(It means a varible?)

Comment: @Sayakiss: please follow all the links given to you. They explain a lot, much better than we could in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

If vi/vim is invoked from inside the pipeline, the `stdin` is connected to the previous pipeline's output, not the terminal. vi/vim is an interactive command, that needs to receive its input from the terminal (tty).

**Bottomline:** You can't pipe to xargs vim, since vim expects input to come from an **interactive terminal**.

If you closely at your terminal you will note vi/vim writing this:

> Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

**PS:** You can use:

```
cat file | xargs vim -Nu NONE
```

To avoid this and make vi/vim non-interactive.

Comment: The `-Nu NONE` trick doesn't work here. The terminal is still garbled after I quit vim.

Comment: @Marco: Pls see this post for more options on running vim non interactively: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-vim-script-in-a-non-interactive-mode

Answer (score 1):

I think Basile's answer explained well for the reason of why your terminal gets screwed up. also he gave a solution `stty sane`.

When I want to open files as result of `find, grep -l ...(in your case, the cat too)` I do:

```
vim $(find . ...)
```

you could try:

```
vim $(cat a.txt)
```

Zhu Ni Hao Yun. :)

Comment: I don't know what is the meanning of `$`...Counld you please elaborate it?(It means a varible?)

Comment: We don't have the time to teach you that much. I gave you a lot of useful links. Please follow them and read them. And yes, learning Linux takes time!